# Trying to run AWS Amplify in a TyppScript/React Native project

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm trying to run AWS Amplify in my TypeScript/React Native project this is the code I have in my app file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  // FlatList,
  Button,
} from "react-native";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "./src/aws-exports";
import { withAuthenticator } from "aws-amplify-react-native";
import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
        <Authenticator>
          {({ signOut, user }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>
                Hey {user.username}, welcome to my channel, with auth!
              </Text>
              <Button onPress={signOut} title="Sign out" />
            </View>
          )}
        </Authenticator>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
});

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

When I try to run the app on my iphone using expo go I get the following: "View config getter callback for component 'div' must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter."

It works on web browser but not on my phone and not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but use `<Authenticator>` component **OR** `withAuthenticator()`, not both.

[Amplify Authenticator doc](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator)

> For React, you can use the Authenticator component directly, or wrap
> your app in withAuthenticator Higher-Order Component:

... and you should have `<AmplifyProvider>` in your main file wrapping everything.